# Can a Japanese "Pokemon Gold" Virtual console game be downloaded to an American 3DS/2DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, region-lock

As the title states. Is it possible to use a Japanese VC download code on an American new 2DS XL?

I recently bought all Japanese "boxed" releases since they were cheap but  didn't realize there may be a region lock.

Answer (score 2):

Games are region locked, you will need a code for the region that your 3DS/2DS is from in order to download it.  In other words you'll need a Japanese console to play the region locked Japanese games.

It's the same principle for Pokemon event codes in later games.